# Gephi 0.8.2 launches but won't work on Mac OSX Yosemite. How can I fix it?

Tags: installation, osx-yosemite, gephi

I'm trying to get Gephi to work on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5.  I followed sumnous.github.io instructions--I downloaded Java 6 and edited gephi.conf.  I even deleted Java 7 completely.  Now, when I click on Gephi, it launches, but I get blank dropdown menus and I can't open any files.  Here's a screenshot for you to see the problem: [image: I'm clicking on File in Gephi and the dropdown is empty. Same with most other menu items.]

Is there a way to fix this?  Should I use another version of Gephi?

Answer (score 0):

Not a Mac user myself but this might help: http://clementlevallois.net/gephi/tuto/en/How%20to%20install%20Gephi%20on%20Mavericks%20or%20Yosemite.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was really painful, then I found the answer [here](https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=2570#wrap). It suggests deleting some old gephi folder which in my case (on ubunto) was hidden. For Mac the folder was in the following path: /Users/YourUserName/Library/Application Support (beware of the space character). Try deleting the gephi folder in the suggested path and re-launch gephi.